# How do I make Eclipse remember multiple "states" of what files I opened, as well as their positions?

Tags: eclipse

I am working in Aptana Studio 2.0 (built using the Eclipse platform) and I work on multiple medium sized web app projects involving 15+ files that are *open* in Aptana's IDE. I have some docked on the left, some on the right, some on the top, some in the middle, and some on the bottom.

Aptana currently saves the "docked" positions of the open files even after restarting, which is great. However, I'm working on multiple, medium sized projects, each with its own set of open files and positions. That means when I switch from "Project A" to "Project B", I'll have to reopen all the files for "Project B" and close all the files open from "Project A". Not only that, but I also have to resize the panels that hold the code, and re-dock/rearrange them as needed. This is a really, really annoying and meticulous process I could do without.

So is there an easy way to make Aptana remember the open files/positions for each of my projects? If so, how do I do it?